# Invalid texture dislplaying

Tags: texturing, distort

I'm using Blender 2.83.2 and I tried to create a carbon fiber texture, following steps shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXSxSXya4y8). It definitely worked when I applied it on a simple meshs (plane, cube, sphere etc created in object or edit mode):

[image: Carbon fiber texture on UV Sphere]

But when I try to change something in a mesh, texture goes distorted and sometimes even loses different colors. For example:

I created a plane in edit mode and it has normal texture. Then I just extruded one of its edges and moved it away so it can be illuminated. But its texture is the colors of the edge (it was extruded from) that are stretched along it. Then, in the same mesh, I created another plane and deleted one of its vertices and created a new face using "New Edge/Face from Vertices" (triangle on a picture below). And it has only the color:

[image: Distorted textures]

I tried deleting the material (in the object properties and even in the .blend file) and applying it again; restarting Blender and computer; switching shading from textured to solid and back; rendering a picture using camera (textures didn`t change). All normals are directed properly.

I am not professional in Blender yet (i don't even know how shader editor works, I just repeated all from that video). So I wonder why this happens and how can i fix it and not to get this problem again.

Comment: You need to UV unwrap your mesh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change things about the mesh the UV for the textures doesn't actually update. To do that, you just need to click "u" on your keyboard and choose unwrap. You can also open the UV editor and make more complex changes from there.

Comment: Yep, that worked!